# How to compare variable with value in an Android make file

Tags: makefile

I have a make file in which I want to compare a variable with a value:

```
SOME_SDK_VERSION?=1.32.0.555

ifeq ($(SOME_SDK_VERSION),1.32.0.555)
    $(info --- in if branch)
else
    $(info --- in else branch)
endif
```

However, when running this makefile, I get the following error: "Android.mk:118: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop."

what's going on?

Comment: The snippet you posted seems to be correct. Also the error message tells us that it must be something other than the `make` syntax `ifeq...`. Can you post line 118?

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue. For some reason, $(info must be indented using spaces, not tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The make file as posted is correct. The issue was with indentation of $(info --- in if branch) - spaces vs tabs